# How to start a complex function automatically as the Server System boots

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a function which is continously reading data from pbx system a hardware device..Now as per my requirement i have to start this function executing at the boot time of the server system.Suppose the server system shuts down due to any problem but as soon as it reboots it should invoke the function whcih is reading data from pbx device ..

Currently i have implemented it in windows form application which is running as service on the system but now i have the requirement to integarte it with the ASP.Net web application delpoyed on server.

Comment: Visit this link for more ideas http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3990/Simple-Windows-Service-Sample

Comment: @Shekhar Sir i need the solution in web application deployed on iis.Currently i have the solution as windows service..

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for. Are you wanting to know how to create an asp.net website? How to start a website at bootup?

Comment: Its indeed unclear sir.

Comment: @DavidArno i want to know how to start a function automatically as soon as the iis server starts

Comment: You already know how to do that: you start your function via a service.

Comment: You made it even less clear "as soon as the iis server starts" and "soon as it reboots" are completely unrelated events... Consider editing your post to decide when you want your code to run.

Comment: If i were u , i had write the code that works in windows form and ask for help in achieving the same result in asp.net. Some people will get the better understanding from your code or the method that is invoke in the windows form. Just my thinking though..

Comment: asp.net global app_start event?